# python boto3を使用してaws s3のオブジェクトを一括ダウンロードしたい

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

現在非常にもどかしい状態になっているので、どうかお力添えを頂けましたら幸いです。

S3にある複数のオブジェクトをpythonのboto3を使用してダウンロードしようとしています。
その際にオブジェクトをワイルドカードを使用してダウンロードしたいのですができません。

AWS CLIであれば下記コマンドで実現できる処理です。

```
aws s3 cp 
　--recursive \
  --exclude '*' \
  --include 'オブジェクト名（ワイルドカードを記載）' \   # test*.csvのような形で記載しています。
  s3://バケット名/フォルダ名 .
```

pythonを使用してLambdaで動かしたいのですが、最悪できなかったらbashでやろうかと思っています。

boto3を使用したファイルダウンロードは下記の書き方だとファイル一つであればダウンロードができることを確認できています。
※aws configureは設定できています。

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Bucket('オブジェクト名').download_file('フォルダ名/オブジェクト名', 'ダウンロード先パス')
```

boto3の参照ドキュメント
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html?highlight=s3%20download#S3.Bucket.download_file

ググり倒した結果
↓でいける！と思ったのですが、osライブラリ等あまりわかっておらず、pythonのコードをどこをどう弄ったら良いのかわからず、現在すこしめげております。

[S3 バケットから複数のファイルを一括でコピーする](https://www.saintsouth.net/blog/how-to-copy-multi-files-from-s3/)

もしpythonがお得意で解決方法等わかる方いればご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: 参考: [Download multiple files from specific "subdirectory", AWS S3 with boto3 & Python 3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65020818/2322778)